# Absorption Time of Continuous Markov Chains

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, stochastic-processes, markov-process

I have the following question about the Absorption Times of Markov Chains in Continuous State-Space.

I was reading the following article on Absorption Times of Markov Chains (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain), but it only references Markov Chains in Discrete State-Space. I am interested in learning about Absorption Times of Markov Chains in Continuous State-Space. To illustrate my question, I thought of the following example (using the R programming language):

Suppose you have a Bivariate Normal Distribution with the following properties:

- `Mean = c(10, 10)`
- `Sigma = matrix( c(1,0.5, 0.5, 1), # the data elements nrow=2, # number of rows ncol=2, # number of columns byrow = TRUE) # fill matrix by rows`

I am interested in knowing "on average, how many (pairs of) random numbers do you need to generate from this Bivariate Normal Distribution until a value of of (12,12) is exceeded?

I tried to answer to this question using a computer simulation:

```
Sigma = matrix(
  c(1,0.5, 0.5, 1), # the data elements
  nrow=2,              # number of rows
  ncol=2,              # number of columns
  byrow = TRUE)        # fill matrix by rows

res <- matrix(0, nrow = 0, ncol = 3)    

for (j in 1:1000){
  e_i = data.frame(matrix(mvrnorm(n = 1, c(10,10), Sigma), ncol=2))
  i <- 1
  while(e_i$X1[1] < 12 | e_i$X2[1] < 12) {
    e_i = data.frame(matrix(mvrnorm(n = 1, c(10,10), Sigma), ncol=2))
    i <- i + 1
  }
  x <- c(e_i$X1, e_i$X2  ,i)
  res <- rbind(res, x)
}

res = data.frame(res)
```

The results of this simulation look as follows:

```
plot(hist(res$X3, breaks = 300))
```

[image]

And here is a summary of the simulation (On my own computer, I changed the number of iterations to 100,000 iterations):

```
summary(res$X3)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
    1.0    71.0   171.0   248.8   347.0  2259.0
```

This tells us that on average, roughly 248 (pairs of) random numbers must be generated from this Bivariate Normal Distribution until a value of (12,12) is exceeded.

**My Question:** In the Wikipedia page I linked above, an example is shown on how to calculate the absorption times of a discrete Markov Chain for "the number of times you need to flip a coin until you get Heads, Tails, Heads":

[image]

**In general, is there an analog of these calculations in Continuous State Space?** For example, is there some formula that could have told me (prior to running the simulation) that a Bivariate Normal Distribution ~ [ mean(10,10) , var(1,0.5,0.5,1) ] would on average require 248 iterations before a value of (12,12) can be observed (i.e. the number of "steps" before absorption)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Let's think about this for a moment. Continuous state space means that there are infinitely many states linked via transition probabilities such that they are all accessible by traversing a single graph (let's suppose). The expected values in such a case are asymptotic, meaning that they either have a cleverly constructed closed form (such as mean of a geometric distribution), or have to be approximated, usually via simulations, such as above.
TLDR: There is no general expression for absorbing states in infinite state markov chains.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In the end, would there have been a formula to obtain the answer 248? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, there would be as the model (Bivariate Normal Distribution) is known apriori, and the sampling is i.i.d.